# c++ Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across ... Points to check for simple worker thread

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog. in this dialog ::OnInitDialog() I create a thread AfxBeginThread((AFX_THREADPROC)MyThreadProc, NULL); It crashes when I close the dialog with run time check failure, and it is pointing to  thrdcore.cpp file (Microsoft Foundation Classes C++ library)

`// first -- check for simple worker thread
    DWORD nResult = 0;
    if (pThread->m_pfnThreadProc != NULL)
    {
        nResult = (*pThread->m_pfnThreadProc)(pThread->m_pThreadParams);
        ASSERT_VALID(pThread);
    }`

 I have a code to kill the thread OnClose function, but it doesn't solve the issue. Can some help, what I am missing? My code for

```
HANDLE m_hExit;
DWORD dwResult = 0;
unsigned threadID = 0;
...


OnInitDialog()
{... 

m_hExit = (HANDLE)AfxBeginThread((AFX_THREADPROC)MyThreadProc, NULL);
}

OnClose()
{

    dwResult = WaitForSingleObject(m_hExit, 0);
if (dwResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
    printf("The thread is still running...\n");
}
else
{
    printf("The thread is no longer running...\n");
}
Sleep(10000);
dwResult = WaitForSingleObject(m_hExit, 0);
if (dwResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
    printf("The thread is still running...\n");
}
else
{
    printf("The thread is no longer running...\n");
}
CDialog::OnClose();

}
```

thread function is very big((((

Comment: The heap or stack is damaged, killing the thread won't solve the problem. The code you're showing is fine, I suspect the error is in the thread function, please paste the code.

Comment: Your cast to AFX_THREADPROC suggests that your thread function may not have the required signature. It must have the documented thread function return type and parameter.

Comment: my function definition UINT WINAPI MyThreadProc( LPVOID pParam )

Comment: definition in the thrdcore.cpp UINT APIENTRY _AfxThreadEntry(void* pParam)

Comment: If I don't close it, it crashes in thread function at the line xx.Format("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", *(p + 5), *(p + 6), *(p + 7), *(p + 8), *(p + 9), *(p + 10), *(p + 11));

Comment: Down vote. great! I am stuck with this run time failure. At list can some one point me to the right direction. Please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AfxBeginThread` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx) as requiring the threadproc to be

```
UINT __cdecl MyControllingFunction( LPVOID pParam );
```

Your comment says your function is

```
UINT WINAPI MyThreadProc( LPVOID pParam )
```

WINAPI is defined as `_stdcall` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

So you have a mismatch of calling conventions. As others already commented, the cast is suspicious. In fact, that's the only reason your code is compiling. If you remove the cast, the compiler should show an error.

The solution is to remove the cast and then fix the calling convention of your function. Once that code compiles correctly without the cast, it should run properly without corrupting the stack.

Comment: Raymond Chen's article that goes into some detail on this problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx  And his related article on using a cast to shut the compiler up: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/23/9911891.aspx

Comment: you were right about cast, after I delete the cast in the function call, which cause compiler complained. Then I changed function definition, it stop complaining and compile fine. Although it didn't solve my problem. My application still crash. At the place which I showed before. I have a while(1) loop inside of this function. It crashes after 4th loop at the xx.Format("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", *(p + 5), *(p + 6), *(p + 7), *(p + 8), *(p + 9), *(p + 10), *(p + 11)); What is going wrong here. If function were able to go through the loop couple times why it crashes?

Comment: @user2001019 I don't have enough information to tell, but since you say it only happens after 4 iterations of the loop, that problem probably involves other code too. Maybe something is setting p to an invalid value or incrementing it until it goes off the end of a buffer.

Comment: Yes you right, condition fail because it was = Null. And program didn't check it and tries access it address. Thank's a lot